# Changing the order of zookeeper nodes

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I have a 3-node zookeeper ensemble running. The configuration entries are like this

```
server.1=0.0.0.0:2888:3888 
server.2=myserver2:2888:3888
server.3=myserver3:2888:3888
```

I want to reduce the number of nodes, and remove myserver2 from the ensemble. Can I just remove the entry for myserver2, shutdown myserver2, and restart the service on the other two? Does zookeeper expect the entries to be in sequence (1,2,3 etc)? Is a 2 node ensemble a bad idea?

Answer (score 0):

> Can I just remove the entry for myserver2, shutdown myserver2, and restart the service on the other two?

Yes you can do that as long as you remove the configuration on every remaining part of the ensemble.

> Does zookeeper expect the entries to be in sequence (1,2,3 etc)?

Not sure how to answer this one. Supposing you mean whether you could define `server.1` and then `server.3` I am not sure that is possible considering the [Administrator guide](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.6.2/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_zkMulitServerSetup). However yo should keep in mind that every quorum member must have a unique id as defined in the myid file for clustered setup. So, if you set myid to a different number than the next in the sequence you should also set it in `zoo.cfg`. More info in the relevant Administrator's guide [section](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.6.2/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_zkMulitServerSetup).

> Is a 2 node ensemble a bad idea?

Short answer: YES.

Long answer: ZooKeeper requires the majority of servers that are part of the ensemble to be up and available. For this reason, it is best to use odd numbers of machines. Using 2 nodes, there is no fault tolerance. If one of them fails, the other one cannot form a majority so the service is not available. A minimum of 3 servers is required for a fault tolerant clustered setup. Citing the Administrator's guide:

> For the ZooKeeper service to be active, there must be a majority of non-failing machines that can communicate with each other. To create a deployment that can tolerate the failure of F machines, you should count on deploying 2xF+1 machines. Thus, a deployment that consists of three machines can handle one failure, and a deployment of five machines can handle two failures. Note that a deployment of six machines can only handle two failures since three machines is not a majority. For this reason, ZooKeeper deployments are usually made up of an odd number of machines.`